# Broadcast receiver. Huge data

Tags: java, android

Does somebody know the max size of content which I can send via broadcast? Is the content transferred in foreground? How the size of data affect on productivity of the device?

Comment: If you have huge data, save it to a temp file and pass just the Uri.

Comment: how much is the "Huge"?

Comment: IHMO a few kb are "huge" for passing with Intent.

Comment: can you show me a simple example with temp file and URI?

Comment: According to my understanding in Java, as large as a data is, it should resides in your memory and only the reference is passed around during broadcast, processing the data is what affects productivity instead of passing it.

Comment: i.e. the size doesn't matter at all?

Comment: Size matters, ridiculously large data throws Out of Memory error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does somebody know the max size of content which I can send via broadcast?

I would expect you to start running into problems around the 1MB mark for the entire parceled `Intent`, as there are limits on `Binder`-based IPC, which underlies the `Intent` system.

> How the size of data affect on productivity of the device?

Since `Intent` objects get copied between processes as a result of broadcasts, you will consume a fair amount of RAM while the broadcast is going on, plus a fair amount of CPU time to copy the memory between processes.

I would agree with rciovati's comment: "IHMO a few kb are "huge" for passing with Intent".

Comment: do calculations appear in asynctask?

Comment: @trololo: I have no idea what "calculations" you are referring to, or how an `AsyncTask` relates to "the max size of content which I can send via broadcast".

Comment: @CommonsWare Do you think does this also apply when broadcasts are local? I mean if it's local, then they wouldn't go out of the owning process boundary and be resolved there (so I assume data limit can be a lot bigger since no IPC would be involved)

Comment: @zgulser: AFAIK, there should be no real limit on the `Intent` size for local broadcasts, other than standard heap space limitations.

Comment: Have not tested but that could be really better than passing your data around using, for example, custom listeners/observers/interfaces.

Comment: @zgulser: In select cases, perhaps. `LocalBroadcastManager` is tied to `Context`, which means it cannot be tested via unit tests very well, only via instrumented tests. Plus, you still have the data type limitations of `Intent` extras to deal with.

Comment: @CommonsWare In my case, my data boundaries only carry serialised JSON. So, type-wise I'm OK. The thing is I usually see people creating those listeners as non-static classes and leak the activity when orientation changes. I was thinking that way you can maybe avoid this issue.